# "free(): invalid next size (fast)" error when trying to free memory of array

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am writing one of the merge sort variations. In my task I use two arrays: keys in `arr` array and values in `brr` array. Keys are integer numbers and values are strings. Merge function receives these two arrays, `l`, `m` and `r` as left, middle and right indexes.

```c
void merge(int arr[], char** brr, int l, int m, int r)
```

I calculate the sizes of two new arrays, that I will need:

```c
int size1 = m-l+1;
int size2 = r-m;
```

To merge arrays, I create two new arrays for keys and strings using `malloc` function:

```c
int* left = malloc(size1*sizeof(int));
int* right = malloc(size2*sizeof(int));
char** lefts = malloc(size1*sizeof(char*));
char** rights = malloc(size2*sizeof(char*));
```

Then I copy values from the input arrays:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++){
    left[i] = arr[l+i];
    lefts[i] = brr[l+i];
}
```

And do sorting steps with new arrays.

```c
i = j = 0;
k = l;
while(i < size1 && j < size2){
    if(left[i] < right[j]){
        brr[k] = lefts[i];
        arr[k] = left[i];
        i++;
    }else{
        brr[k] = rights[j];
        arr[k] = right[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Then I add to `brr` arrays last items and after trying to free memory of `rights` array I get an error.

```c
free(lefts);
lefts = NULL;
free(rights);
rights = NULL;
```

Note: there is no error when trying to free memory of `lefts` array, only `rights`. I tried to swap `free(lefts)` and `free(rights)`, but result is the same.

Full function code:

```c
void merge(int arr[], char** brr, int l, int m, int r){
    int size1 = m-l+1;
    int size2 = r-m;
    int* left = malloc(size1*sizeof(int));
    int* right = malloc(size2*sizeof(int));
    char** lefts = malloc(size1*sizeof(char*));
    char** rights = malloc(size2*sizeof(char*));

    for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++){
        left[i] = arr[l+i];
        lefts[i] = brr[l+i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size2; i++){
        right[i] = arr[m+1+i];
        rights[i] = brr[m+1+i];
    }
    int i, j, k;
    i = j = 0;
    k = l;
    while(i < size1 && j < size2){
        if(left[i] < right[j]){
            brr[k] = lefts[i];
            arr[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            brr[k] = rights[j];
            arr[k] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i < size1){
        brr[k] = lefts[i];
        arr[k] = left[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while(j < size2){
        brr[k] = rights[j];
        arr[k] = right[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    free(left);
    left = NULL;
    free(right);
    right = NULL;
    free(lefts);
    lefts = NULL;
    free(rights);
    rights = NULL;
}
```

MergeSort function:

```c
void mergeSort(int arr[], char** brr, int l, int r){
    if(l < r){
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;
        mergeSort(arr, brr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, brr, m+1, r);
        merge(arr, brr, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

Main:

```c
int main(){
    const int maxStrings = 14;
    const int maxStringSize = 70;
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();

    int *Keys = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < maxStrings; i++) Keys[i] = i;

    char **Strings = malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    char *temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        getStr(&temp, maxStringSize);
        Strings[i] = temp;
    }
    mergeSort(Keys, Strings, 0, n-1);
}
```

getStr:

```c
void getStr(char **a, int n){
    *a = malloc(n*sizeof(char));
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    while( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && i < n-1){
        if(c == EOF){
            (*a)[i] = '\0';
            return;
        }
        (*a)[i++] = c;
    }
    (*a)[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of malloc?

Comment: You've shown us the code that's correct. Now all you need to do is show us the code that has the error. See [mcve]. BTW, it's best *not* to split the code into separate snippets. Just one code block that can be copy/pasted makes it easier for someone to try your code.

Comment: I suggest this prototype, which is more readable: `void merge(int arr[], char *brr[], int l, int m, int r);` and suggest more meaningful names for those arguments.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito, yes `malloc` returns an address, not NULL

Comment: @CacahueteFrito It's not a good idea to "use actual arrays" if the sizes can be big

Comment: The full function code has the potential to be correct. It all depends on the arguments that were passed to it.

Comment: How do you call the function? In other words - shows us the main!

Comment: Those `NULL` assignments at the end can be removed.  Those are local variables, and will disappear

Comment: Well, it seems very hard to get the full code... Now we don't have `getStr`. Anyway - I'm 99.99% sure that you overwrite some dynamic allocated memory and thereby destroy the "allocation book keeping" for `rights` BTW: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254782/a-long-list-of-possible-duplicates-c-memory-allocation-and-overrunning-bounds for a list of possible answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is typically a sign of overwriting some memory that doesn't belong to you. Typically you have destroyed the "mallocs book-keeping data" for the variable you are freeing.

So look for illegal memory writes. How about this code?

```
int *Keys = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for(int i = 0; i < maxStrings; i++) Keys[i] = i;
```

You `malloc` only `n` elements but still you write `maxStrings` elements. So if `n` is less than `maxStrings` you have a write out side allocated memory.

Comment: ty, now it is working, but why the error was only with `rights` array?

Comment: @MaximCheremisinov Probably because the illegal write only destroyed the book-keeping for `rights` while the others variables wasn't touched

Answer (score 2):

In your main, this: `for(int i = 0; i < maxStrings; i++)` should be up to `n`, instead of up to `maxStrings` no?